# ABAP hard code value into SELECT and field into another field

Tags: abap, opensql

It is possible in ABAP to make a select and include a  hard code value and to put a value in any field.

In my exemple I have to fill a range with Company code BUKRS according to VKORG so I have to do a select on TVKO like that:

```
DATA : lt_rtvko TYPE RANGE OF bukrs.

  SELECT    'I' as sign 'EQ' as option bukrs as low 
  INTO      CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_rtvko
  FROM      tvko
  WHERE     vkorg EQ p_vkorg.
```

But I have a dump.

I know a longer solution to do this, To fill manually a table of TVKO and make a LOOP to fill the range, BUT I am sure that we have a solution to do that in one operation like in my example.

Thanks, Experts.

Comment: What does the dump say? And why don't you remove `CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy. Just get rid of `INTO CORRESPONDING` and `AS`. As long as the value order is right, you get no problem:

```
SELECT 'I', 'EQ', bukrs
  FROM tvko
  INTO TABLE @lt_rtvko
 WHERE vkorg = @p_vkorg.
```

And I think you have a typo in your range declaration. Should be:

```
DATA: lt_rtvko TYPE RANGE OF bukrs.
```

Comment: Yeah you have right, i corriged it to type of range BUKRS. And What the @ mean ?i didn't know this syntax!

Comment: @shmoolki It's the new OpenSQL Syntax. The `@` symbol marks symbols as host variables. There's litteraly no magic function applied. Same goes for commas in the selection list. Just for the optics. Read [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/abap/blog/2014/02/06/abap-news-for-release-740-sp05)